# Use ListView as background of TextView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have the below layout which contain mainly:

Relative layout, which act as header with Textview and button.

and Listview.

I would like to make the "header" which is the above relative layout to be transparent and show the listview as user scroll down the list view.

I know how to make the layout transparent, but I dont know how to show the listview as background for the "header".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/buttonlayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:background="#FFDBE2ED"
             android:paddingBottom="0dp"
              android:paddingTop="0dp" 
             >
          <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
                android:gravity="center_vertical" 
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:text="@string/list_header"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold">
            </TextView>



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
                android:layout_marginRight="3px"
                android:layout_marginTop="6px"
                android:height="0dp"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:width="70dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  >
            </Button>
       </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>



</LinearLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a LinearLayout as the root container and in linear layout the views are placed one over the other so you cannot overlap one view over the other. If you want an overlapping effect you can use either the FrameLayout or the RelativeLayout as the root container.
Using RelativeLayout is a better option. 
Here is sample code for this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#00cc0000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here the button is overlapping the list view.

I hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you ... I tried it, but I'm getting error:E/AndroidRuntime(  393): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{.MessagesActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastExce
ption: android.widget.TextView

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the ListView inside of your RelativeLayout, as the first element (this ensures that it's in the back). This way, the other views are just on top of the ListView, and if you make them transparent you should get the desired effect!
Oh, and you should make the ListView then fill the RelativeLayout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

, and make the RelativeLayout fill the screen:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
...
```

Comment: I got error: java.lang.ClassCastExcetion: android.widget.TextView

Comment: Hmm, weird. Are you using ids in your layouts multiple times? What exactly are you trying to cast? I'm assuming you use a findViewById call?